# How to copy all rows that have specific values in multiple columns excel?

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

I am trying to copy all rows from an excel sheet `Sheet1` that have a specific value in column `A` and `B`. and then paste them into a new sheet `Sheet2`. My specific example is I have figured out that I want to copy the rows that have a `0` in Column `A` as well as `4000` in Column `B`.

The problem that I am having is that the code copies all rows that have a `0` in column `A` not just the ones that meet both conditions.

My code is below for reference:

```
Sub Temp_copy()
    set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
    set e = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim d
    Dim j
    d = 1
    j = 2

    Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("A" & j))
        If i.Range("A"&j) = Range("B6"&j) And i.Range("B" & j) = Range(B"10"&j) Then
            d=d+1
            e.Rows(d).Value=i.Rows(j).Value
        End If
        j = j+1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Hopefully that makes sense. I am new to VBA so any help or guidance to achieve what I need would be muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `AutoFilter()` method of `Range` object, as follows (explanations in comments):

```
Sub foo()
    Dim wsResult As Worksheet
    Set wsResult = Sheets("Sheet02")

    With Worksheets("Sheet01")
        With .Range("A2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) 'reference its columns A:B cells from row 2 (header) down to last not empty one in column "A" (If you need to copy more columns than simply adjust "A2:B" to whatever columns range you need)
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="0" ' filter referenced cells on 1st column with "0" content
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="4000" ' filter referenced cells on 2nd column with "4000" content
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("A1") ' if any filtered cell other than the header then copy their first five columns and paste to 'wsResult' sheet starting from its column A last not empty cell
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Works perfectly. I am now trying to take this a step higher.
I would like to have multiple conditions that can be considered. What I mean is
have the initial condition that we discussed before (the 0 in column A and 4000 in Column B) but also consider all rows that have a  2 In column A and 8000 in column B. Im thinking to add an Or statement but unsure where to put it.

Is what I am asking even possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. You could simply duplicate the code and first copy/paste the cells meeting the first condition and then copy/paste the cells meeting the second condition. Or you could duplicate the code and make an Union of the two ranges and then copy/paste it. Or use the multiple conditions pattern allowed by AutoFilter (see documentation in msdn site

Comment: I know have a sheet that has data in columns A to E, G to K and M to Q. Im trying to obtain all values that are '0' (referenced from "C1") and '12.05' (this is referenced from cell "C2" that are in the 4th column of each respective row. for this I have used a similar code to above but used field = 4 instead of =1 and changed the with statement to .Range("A1:E & cells . rows.count, "D"); ("G1:K & cells . rows.count, "J" and so on. Is that correct? The issue I know have is that only the values that are '0' are copied an pasted. Any idea why this is so?

Comment: I believe it is due to the code only being able to read whole numbers? is there a way around that?

Comment: It may be a matter of number formatting: the cell in excel UI is showing ‘12.05’ but the actual value could be some ‘12.054269’. You’d better post a new question with the new scenario along with proper details (some screenshots of data).

Comment: cheers for that, I have asked here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894046/how-to-read-decimal-number-from-cell-and-copy-all-rows-that-have-that-cell-numbe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Temp_Copy()
    Dim cl As Range, rw As Integer

    rw = 1
    For Each cl In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10") //Set range as needed
        If cl = 0 And cl.Offset(0, 1) = 4000 Then
            cl.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rw)
            rw = rw + 1
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```