# How to read decimal number from cell and copy all rows that have that cell number - EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, decimal, copy-paste

I am trying to read a number from a Cell (this number changes so I have referenced the cell) and then copy it to a new sheet. There are no issues with the reading or copying. The issue I have is that the number that is being read from another cell doesn't work with decimal numbers. I can read cells with all whole numbers and copy their respective rows but just not decimals. I have tried a work around solution that rounded the numbers to whole numbers but later found this just wont work for the accuracy required in my solution.

A Snippet of code is below:

```
With ws.Result.Range ("A1:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
.AutoFilter Field := 6, Criteria1 := wsResult.Range("J1") ' checks row F to see 
whether the number in cell J1 matches any in row F

If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)>1 Then .
Offset(1). Resize (.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 
Destination:= Main.Range("A22") ' Paste all rows starting at A22 on the main page.
```

I know the rest of the code works as planned its purely just being able to get the numbers that
 are decimal to work.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: might be 15 digit floating point problems. try rounding to a large number of decimal points; e.g round(a1, 14)

Comment: cheers, the max amount of decimal places are 3 but still wont work

Comment: 3 *display* decimals, or 3 actual underlying decimals ?

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean by that. The max is for example 12.435

Comment: Did you check the formatting of the destination cell? Could be the cell format is cutting the decimals off

Comment: I don't think it is to do with the formatting of the destination cell as when it is a decimal place nothing is pasted to the new sheet at all. This makes me think that either when the matching is occurring that it only registers the whole number and thus wont see an exact match but not sure...

maybe I should put a "Double" command somewhere?

Comment: You're not using the correct syntax for passing named arguments: for example `Field = 6` should be `Field := 6`  Or maybe you just need to fix up your posted code?

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I have it correct in my actual code, I'll fix it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get around any decimal formatting issue, you could try the following code (explanations in comments):

```
With wsResult ' be sure 'wsResult' is properly set to a valid 'WorkSheet' object before reaching this line
    With .Range("A1:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row) 'reference its columns A:F cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one in column "F"
        .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & Round(.Range("J1").Value2, 3) - 0.0001, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Round(.Range("J1").Value2, 3) + 0.0001 ' filter referenced cells on 6th column with content in a range of 0.0001 from referenced range "J1" cell content rounded to three decimals
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Main.Range("A22") ' if any filtered cell other than the header then copy and paste them to 'Main' worksheet starting from its A22 cell
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

and should your actual cell content decimal separator be a dot (`.`), then be sure to substitute the comma (`,`) decimal separator read from "J1" cell content with a dot by changing:

```
        .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & Round(.Range("J1").Value2, 3) - 0.0001, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Round(.Range("J1").Value2, 3) + 0.0001 ' filter referenced cells on 6th column with content in a range of 0.0001 from referenced range "J1" cell content rounded to three decimals
```

to

```
        .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & Replace(Round(.Range("J1").Value2, 3) - 0.0001, ",", "."), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Replace(Round(.Range("J1").Value2, 3) + 0.0001, ",", ".") ' filter referenced cells on 6th column with content in a range of 0.0001 from referenced range "J1" cell content rounded to three decimals
```

as a side note, just be aware that `.Range("J1")` is pointing at the cell in the first row and 10th column of the referenced range. 
In this case your referenced range starts from cell "A1" of referenced `wsResult` worksheet, so that is equivalent to`wsResult.Range("J1")`.

Comment: Thanks!
I later have found that I am dealing with numbers that have up to 10 decimal places. 
would changing the code to below work?
.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & Round(.Range("J1").Value2, 10) - 0.00000000001, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Round(.Range("J1").Value2, 8) + 0.00000000001

Comment: Well, go ahead and try it yourself! And if my answer provided the solution to your original question then please consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Couldn't get it to work. instead I rounded the larger numbers to 3 decimal points.
Thanks for all your help

Comment: You are welcome. So my answer didn’t solve the question, did it?

Comment: It works for the three decimal points however i couldn't get it to work for the 10. not sure if its an excel issue or not but for my solution to the three decimal points was accurate enough. thanks for everything